# Backbone - Action already captured design

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So some background.
Let's say I have a notice on the page (like a success or error message). This is managed by a collection of Notice models.

When a new notice is added to the collection a region displays it in my page.
But let's now say that I have a view somewhere deep and nested, which when shown should instead display the notice (instead of the other region) until the end of its life.

What method would be clean for managing this?

- Adding an attribute to the model to say `is_global` or something similar
- Registering upon view creation that this view will take over responsibility. Then unregistering upon removal.
- Some other crazy method

Comment: so you have some region, listening to NoticeCollection and re-render this  on add. Some other nested view also render NoticeCollection, but what the difference between region and nested view ?

Comment: @Evgeniy nothing is different between them. However, the page region is there as a kind of global space if another region does not manage them.
An example would be a login view. I would want the notice to be rendered in the login view's notice region, but not in the global space (as having dual notices looks messy).

Comment: What about a displayed property? With the right render order (subviews ending with the global view) whatever view takes responsibility for rendering the notice flags it as displayed and all subsequent renderings avoid redrawing the notice. When the view unloads the notice, the flag is reset. This is sort of a combination of your first two bullets.

Comment: @kaminari like the concept. But in backbone the events are responded to in the order of bindings. Of course the global binding is going to go first...

Comment: @jshthornton indeed, that is the tricky part of how this problem is posed. The difficulty is in how this single notification stream can be directed to the appropriate view. Appropriate, as I gather, is a view that has current "focus" (despite its nesting) and may lend itself to an answer. I could envision a system where a view is flagged as "focused" or "current" at which point, in its render process, it renders the notification (all other unflagged don't). Not all views have to have this property, only ones with a reference to the NoticeCollection.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your problem correctly:

> You have a queue of notices and depending on the notice they can appear 
>   in different parts of the page

I would say that you should add a property of some sort to the model and, on each add, emit an event related to that property value.  This way any view can listen to the event and handle the notice appropriately.  This will also keep your notification queue decoupled from the handling view